# slicing pandas df based on repeated cycle values in a particular column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

I have df like below (Example)

```
index       y       z
0           118     .
1           118     .
2           118     .
3           116
4           116
5           110
6           110
7           104
8           104
.
.
.
.
.
320         3       .
321         3       .
322         3
323         7
324         7
328         11
329         11
.
.
.
350         25
351         25
```

As you can see in `column y` the values starts from `118` and it keeps on `decreasing` till `number 3` at index `322`. Again it keeps `increasing` from `index 323 of value 7` and it reaches the value of `25` at `index 351.`

Also you can find the repeated value in column y. (`118 repeated thrice, 116 repeated twice and so on....`)

## My Requirement

I would like to slice the first part of that df.(`Value from 118 to` 3)
i.e., `from index 0 till 322`.

**how my df should look like**

```
index       y       z
0           118     .
1           118     .
2           118     .
3           116
4           116
5           110
6           110
7           104
8           104
.
.
.
.
.
320         3       .
321         3       .
322         3
```

I believe that there should be an alternate pythonic way which make it easier. (In-built function or using `numpy`) Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `df` as the input dataframe and index in the sequence - `0,1,..`, you can do -

```
df.iloc[:(df.y.shift()<df.y).idxmax()[0]]
```

For a generic index format, you can do -

```
df.iloc[:(df.y.shift()<df.y).to_numpy().argmax()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [106]: df
Out[106]: 
      y         z
7   118  0.149675
8   118  0.386489
9     3  0.449950
10    3  0.902349
11    8  0.969809
12   11  0.170910

In [107]: df.iloc[:(df.y.shift()<df.y).to_numpy().argmax()]
Out[107]: 
      y         z
7   118  0.149675
8   118  0.386489
9     3  0.449950
10    3  0.902349
```

We can also use slicing on the array data -

```
In [108]: a = df.y.to_numpy().ravel()

In [109]: df.iloc[:(a[:-1] < a[1:]).argmax()+1]
Out[109]: 
      y         z
7   118  0.149675
8   118  0.386489
9     3  0.449950
10    3  0.902349
```

Alternatively, with `np.diff` to replace shifted comparison -

```
In [110]: df.iloc[:(np.diff(a)>0).argmax()+1]
Out[110]: 
      y         z
7   118  0.149675
8   118  0.386489
9     3  0.449950
10    3  0.902349
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a copy of the required slice by the following command:

```
df_copy = df.iloc[0:322]
```